# Word which means inevitably successful

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am looking for a noun which means inevitably successful or bound to be a success or ultimately successful.

Comment: 'Certainty' or 'shoo-in' would work in competitive arenas.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am looking to name my venture and hence a noun which is good to pronounce

Comment: How about 'ace'.

Comment: @ChrisM "Ace" is closer to "is successful" than "will be"

Comment: @Slava yeah but he's looking for an easy to pronounce noun which denotes success. If you've got a hand full of aces you're going to win.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. It is not about just success, it is about someone/something which is going to be inevitably successful...

Comment: Can it be 'infallible'?